# Maturin project with Python bindings behind feature

Tags: python, rust, pyo3, maturin

I'm trying to write *optional Python bindings* for a Rust library, using maturin and PyO3. The default layout created by maturin is

```
my-project
├── Cargo.toml
├── python
│   └── my_project
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── bar.py
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
└── src
    └── lib.rs
```

where all Rust code, including the `#[pymodule]` attributes go into `src/lib.rs`:

```
use pyo3::prelude::*;

/// Formats the sum of two numbers as string.
#[pyfunction]
fn sum_as_string(a: usize, b: usize) -> PyResult<String> {
    Ok((a + b).to_string())
}

/// A Python module implemented in Rust.
#[pymodule]
fn rir_generator(_py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(sum_as_string, m)?)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

However, since I want to put all of this code behind a conditional feature, I am trying to put all of that wrapper code into `src/python.rs` and then import it into `src/lib.rs` using

```
#[cfg(feature = "python")]
pub mod python;
```

But building this fails with the warning

> Warning: Couldn't find the symbol `PyInit_my_project` in the native library. Python will fail to import this module. If you're using pyo3, check that `#[pymodule]` uses `my_project` as module name

If I put the code back into `src/lib.rs`, the warning disappears.

Is there a way to put PyO3 bindings into a submodule that is then conditionally imported using features?

Comment: The way it's usually done is by having two libraries, the core library and bindings library that imports the core library.

Comment: I was thinking about that, too, but was a bit discouraged because I don't know how to structure such a project... in a common workspace I presume?

Comment: Yes, a workspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. You need to add following section to the `Cargo.toml` to remove the warning.

```
[features]
default = ["python"]
python = []
```

Quoting from the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html#the-features-section):

> Features are defined in the `[features]` table in Cargo.toml. Each
> feature specifies an array of other features or optional dependencies
> that it enables.

By default, *all features are disabled unless explicitly enabled.* This will cause the native library to build without `PyInit_<module_name>` symbol, Hence the warning.
*This
can be changed by specifying the [`default` feature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html#the-default-feature)*

Comment: Oh, I was actually wondering about that, but didn't know where to look. Thanks!